# Разворачивание div элемента с .slideToggle()

Tags: javascript

На сайте [mywot.com](http://www.mywot.com/) обнаружил приятную плюшку в виде выезжающего скрытого окна авторизации-регистрации (кнопка Login-Register сверху слева страницы). Было хотел извлечь основной код создающий эффект появления и исчезновения (в том числе эффект пелены внизу во время активного элемента авторизации сверху, кстати элемент снизу остается по прежнему активен и выполняет роль кнопки закрывающий верхний), но мгновенно потонул в js коде, ибо до этого с ним не работал, да и тем более в таком объеме.

Может кто показать готовые примеры, касаемые этих эффектов или расписать, как это все работает по порядку, попытаюсь в таком случае погуглить сам. Искренне прошу извинить меня за весь этот сумбур, что я расписал.

Comment: Интересную плюшку вы нашли, тоже заинтересовался. Работает это всё на setTimeout, сейчас поэкспериментирую.

Answer (score 2):

Вот что сделал :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var sr  =   20;
var i   =   sr;
var mx  =   300;
//
function up(cometo) {
    clearTimeout(tm);
    var md              =   document.getElementById('openDiv');
    var tm              =   setInterval(function() {
        if (cometo == 'back') {
            if (i <= sr) {
                clearTimeout(tm);
            } else {
                i--;
                md.style.height =   i+'px';
            }
        } else {
        if (cometo == 'open') { 
            if (i >= mx) {
                clearTimeout(tm);
            } else {
                i++;
                md.style.height =   i+'px';
            }
        }
        }
    }, 10);
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#openDiv {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #FC9;
    width: 500px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="openDiv"><div><label onclick="up('open');">открыть</label></div>1<br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />6<br />7<br />7<br /><br />123123<br /><br />
<br /><div><label onclick="up('back')">закрыть</label></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Работает конечно со страшными ошибками, но уже есть к чему стремиться)

Comment: Уберите кучу бр, не пугайте народ ;) С уважением :)

Comment: Иначе кнопок не видно будет(

Comment: А как же отступы? margin-padding? В код не смотрел, но уверен на 100%, что можно переверстать более красиво и элегантно, нежели куча бр. С уважением :)

Comment: Это понятно, и не конечный вариант, безусловно в дальнейшем он будет красивее.

Comment: Спасибо Kremchik и Андрею Аршинову за помощь, с открытием/закрытием разобрался, но вот второй вопрос по-прежнему вызывает затруднения, а конкретно - засветление нижней области страницы, которая остается активной и выполняет уже роль "большой кнопки" закрывающей верхний див. Застветление происходит именно в тот момент, когда верхняя анимация полностью отработана и наоборот соответственно

Comment: Скорее всего добавляется, или показывается слой поверх всего документа.

Comment: Я немного изменил свой вариант так, что осталось только решить вопрос "большой кнопки".

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, вам нужно [это](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/animatedcollapse.htm). (с jQuery)

Выглядеть оно может так:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yandex.st/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/animatedcollapse.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    animatedcollapse.addDiv('login_form', 'fade=1, speed=700, height=0px');
    animatedcollapse.ontoggle=function($, divobj, state) {
        if (state == "none") {
            $("#allother").css("opacity", "1");
        } else {
            $("#allother").css("opacity", "0.4");
        }
    }
    animatedcollapse.init();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="login_form" style="width: 100%; display:none">
        Login form
    </div>
    <div id="allother">
    <a href="#" onclick="animatedcollapse.toggle('login_form')">login</a>
    <hr />
    <p>... The Page<br />...</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Это чуть изменённая версия, осталось только решить последнюю часть, как сделать так, чтобы на время раскрытой формы вся остальная страница выполняла роль кнопки.

Второй скрипт в хеде лучше скачать и добавить себе.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на вопрос большой кнопки:
растягиваете div на оставшуюся область экрана с `position:fixed`, делаете его полупрозрачным и с белым фоном, вешаете обработчик на событие onclick и благополучно скрываете форму логина :)

Comment: Возникает вопрос, может ли кнопка быть внутри этой страницы. Если онклик поставить, то по нажатию на основную кнопку разворачивания два онклика срабатывает, один поставленный, а один - ontoggle который. Это в варианте с jQuery.